# Saving decryptable password

Tags: encryption, password-storage

I know there was question like this million times, but I was unable to find answer that will fit my needs.

I'm building something like small internal password manager for my company, to store login data for various servers and so on.
When new user is registered, his password will be saved in database in salted/hashed version so no one can get access to it (and for that part I think it's all ok, correct me if I'm wrong).

But then, when user is logged in, he is able to add new server with it's login details.

Question is, how to store those.

Because, at some point, I have to present this login details to user in plain text (that is whole point of this application).
Best I could came up with is using some kind of symmetric encryption.
Idea is that app will crypt login details with symmetric encryption and save it in that way into database, and then when data is needed once again will extract data from database, decrypt it with same key and present to user (and key should be in source code of application?).

It could be asymmetric encryption but it's the same if public and private key are stored in same source code, then there is no any benefit of using it?

That doesn't seem too secure, but I can't think of anything better.

Is there any better way to do this, to store this login data?

If it's important to you, application will be in PHP and database is Oracle

Comment: Services like passpack.com handle decryption of the data client-side only …

Comment: If this is your first time dealing with encryption, I'd think twice about building this vs. buying something that already exists.  There are some great password managers out there that have had a lot of scrutiny applied to them.

Comment: Agreed. This is a very difficult problem to implement securely and definitely should not be someone's first cryptography project to store other people's passwords. If you want to start learning the issues involved, I recommend 1Password's white paper on the subject. https://1password.com/files/1Password%20for%20Teams%20White%20Paper.pdf. (I also am very fond of 1Password as a password vault, but there are many good products out there.)

Comment: Buy a well vetted password manager, don't roll your own. Getting security correct is very hard even for seasoned cryptographers and there result of a cryptographic failure will expose all passwords and he catastrophic.

Comment: Yes, this is my first time with encryption on this level. And second, security is not really a issue here, because in real situation app (and database) will be accessible only by from our internal network (not over the internet) and only by users who can really see data. Now those users have excel file on their computer with passwords, and passwords are know by all of us..So basically, anything I do is security upgrade, not a security problem :) But I would like to make it as good as I can. Off course buying already built solution is more secure, but learning is what I'm trying to do here

Answer (score 0):

I would just use symmetric encryption. The standard steps are:

- Derive a symmetric key from a user-supplied password (e.g. PBKDF2 or scrypt)
- Encrypt the data using AES-128-CBC or better with a good random IV
- HMAC the result (e.g. HMAC_SHA256) or just use AES GCM mode

Store IV+ciphertext+MAC in the database.

This can all run in a browser these days (see crypto-js and aes-js). That way the server never gets to see the plaintext password (not sure if this is a requirement).

The MAC can also serve as a password hash, i.e. if the MAC validation fails, then it means the supplied password is incorrect.

Comment: The chance of the OP getting a password manager correctly secure is minuscule so the correct answer is **"don't"**.

Comment: If I derive symmetric key from user password, then for every server I should store different password for each user? That seems like a lot of work when password for server changes (changing password for each user using all of that)? It seems easier to use user accounts to allow access to information that that user can see, and use app in some way to encrypt and decrypt data, so when password is changed I have to change it only once

Comment: Well in that case you might as well not encrypt anything. If the server contains the encryption key and encrypted data, then when it's hacked, the encrypted data is easily decrypted.

Comment: That is why I had idea that database has encrypted data and app has encryption key. In that way you can get access to database but will be unable to decrypt data

Comment: I see, I think you misunderstand the key derivation process. From the same password you will still get the same key. [Key derivation](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/16354/whats-the-advantage-of-using-pbkdf2-vs-sha256-to-generate-an-aes-encryption-key) is needed to slow down brute forcing. That's all.